# How to enable ido-completing-read correctly

Tags: customize, ido

So there is `ido-completing-read` that seems perfect to assign to `completing-read-function`. There is no customization interface though.

How is the user supposed to enable `ido-completing-read` for all completing reads?

Comment: Have a look at the [Emacswiki page for Ido](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) for details.

Comment: Emacswiki page does not mention `completing-read-function` so I guess wiki is older than the function (it uses `defadvice`). Does not really answer my question....

Comment: Did you try turning on `ido`?

Comment: I see no difference whether `ido-mode` is enabled or `ido-mode` is disabled.

Comment: Hmm... you could either try the package `ido-ubiquitous`, or else just set the variable by hand: `(setq completing-read-function #'completing-read-ido)`.

Comment: https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous

Comment: `(setq completing-read-function #'completing-read-ido)` won't work because `completing-read-ido` doesn't handle all the different collection types that `completing-read-function` might receive ([bug#15430](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=bug%2315430)).

Answer (score 2):

Seems that convetions is to provide a customization per each package separatelly:

- Org Mode: `(setq org-completion-use-ido t)`
- Magit: `(setq magit-completing-read-function 'magit-ido-completing-read)`
- Gnus: `(setq gnus-completing-read-function 'gnus-ido-completing-read)`

Or use https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous that tries to do the correct thing always.

Comment: This is not a convention it's rather that some packages support it while `ido-ubiquitous` is just a hack to use `ido` wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Basic setup is just:

```el
(setq
 ido-create-new-buffer    'always
 ido-enable-flex-matching t
 ido-everywhere           t)

(ido-mode 1) ; ido for switch-buffer and find-file
```

Next, to use it everywhere install `ido-ubiquitous` and activate it:

```el
(ido-ubiquitous-mode 1) ; use IDO everywhere
```

`ido-vertical` is highly recommended:

```el
(setq ido-vertical-define-keys 'C-n-and-C-p-only)

(ido-vertical-mode 1) ; display IDO vertically
```

---

Don't forget about [Smex](https://github.com/nonsequitur/smex).